# How to find whether the selected item is Numeric and alphabet in listbox using JQUERY?

Tags: jquery

I have created two listboxes wherein i can move the values from one another..but before moving I need to validate the entries..for which I need to know whether it is numeric or alpha!

I have searched this awesome site and found the way to get the selected item like this.

```
select.find('option:selected').text();
```

Can somebody help me on this please?

Comment: If you could post some more code to see what exactly your requirement is.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has `isNaN()` (isNotaNumber) for that :

```
if ( isNaN( select.find('option:selected').text() ) ) {
    // It's not a number
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hHfNs/3/)

Comment: Hi @adeneo ..thanks for the comments but i need this stuff in JQUERY..please help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(select.find('option:selected').text().match('^[0-9]+$')){
    // its numeric
 }
 else{
   // it's alpha
 }
```